# Get a Certificate from a Signed assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, pfx

So i signed an assembly when i compiled it in VS.

[image: Visual studio Signing section]

Is there a way (within that program, or from another one) to get that PFX certificate and export it from a DLL/EXE using C#? Once the program is compiled, could it have a function on itself to export that certificate?

Comment: Why do you assume that the certificate gets embedded in the assembly?

Comment: that's one of the points of the question, i found a method to get a public key from an assembly, but not sure if it's possible to recover it all back

Comment: If the full certificate was embedded, a malicious third party could potentially extract it (what you're basically asking for) and make a forged copy of the assembly, rendering the signing pointless.

Comment: indeed, makes sense.

Comment: You can get the certificate with its public key, not the private key that signed the certificate (PFX is a private key, CER is just the certificate). What do you actually need?

Comment: i was going to make the program sign a "child" file with it's own certificate - but the previous comments made sense, really would be pointless to store the entire certificate on the compile code, so i'll add one as a resource or something like that, and use it so sign child files

Comment: Note that that in itself is unsafe. Ideally you would store the private key in the normal Windows private key store